# It seems that void *self in ex19 Learn C The Hard Way isn't being called

Tags: c, oop

I've been working on exercise 19 of Learn C The Hard Way for 3 days and I don't really get it. Why would you need void *self if it isn't being called in main function for example:

```
int Monster_attack(void *self, int damage)
{
   Monster *monster = self;
   printf("You attack %s!\n", monster->_(description));
   etc....
   etc....
}
```

throughout all the files I don't see it being called in main function I only see

```
Map *game = NEW(Map, "The Hall of the Minotaur.");
```

does the self pointer automatically take the Object after being declared?
for example:

```
Object object;
```

inside the implementation the pointer to function automatically do this?

```
int Monster_attack(object, some_integer);
```

The source code are [here](https://github.com/fbmnds/lcthw/blob/master/ex19.c)

I am sorry about my grammar because English is not my native language, and I am hoping it's clear enough.

Comment: AFAICS this won't make sense to the reader without this line from -obj.h: `#define _(N) proto.N`. But it's still pretty horrible. Is there are a good reason you're casting away the object types and then casting them back again?

Comment: so what is the void *self used for? I don't really get it, I know that it is a pointer to function but without variable or object it won't run right? so does it automatically run that way or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are using `void*` to emulate objects.

In C++ you would declare `attack()` as a member function of the class `Monster` and then call it like this: `myMonster.attack(damage);`

In C, since we don't have classes, they are emulating classes by using an extra parameter to pass a reference to the struct that holds the object state:
`Monster_attack(myMonster, damage);`

So `void *self` is a pointer to a struct that holds the member variables of an object (struct) of the appropriate type.

To make the member functions easily recognizable they use the naming convention `<class>_<function>(void* self, ...)`.

Comment: now I get it, at first I didn't see the init fuction being called in object.c, I suppose the source code is a bit messy... well now I see the part of calling I didn't realize at first el->init(el) and el->destroy(el). so my assumption is a right that It call itself.